# problem in installing ubuntu parallel to windows 8

Tags: grub2, windows-8, ext4, exfat

I have partitioned my hard drive and selected exFAT file system. I installed ubuntu on my labtop using pendrive and when installation I completedI get this error "radeon 0000:0a:00.0: VCE init error (-22)". When the system is rebooted system directly boots to windows without displaying grub menu.
Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Ubuntu can't be installed on exFAT file system.

Comment: but i have onlt two options: ntfs , exFAT

Comment: Where do you have these two options? In Windows? You need to partition disk from Ubuntu LiveUSB. And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I partitioned drive into c and f, while formatting f drive I got a question select one file type: nfts,exFAT. I system has windows 8 and i5 processor. Is this why I cannot have dual operating system? I am installing ubuntu16.04